# Silicon Diode problems

Tags: diodes, power-electronics

[image: Silicon diode problems]

Hi guys i just learned a new topic last week and i was unsure on these questions.
Does anyone know how to determine in the diagram if it's forward-biased or reverse-biased?
How can i calculate the diode current in the diagram. Thanks

Voltage at X= 10v

Voltage from X to Z

10v-(-20v) = 30v

Voltage at Vxy= 10k/20k x 30v = 15v

voltage at Y= 10v-15v= -5v

Comment: Are you familiar with Thévenin and superposition?

Comment: Can you tell me what forward bias means ? Can you tell me what reverse bias means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Forward bias" means that the polarity of the voltage applied to the diode causes it to conduct. "Reverse bias" means that the polarity is reversed, and the diode does not conduct. Remember that conventional current (flowing from positive to negative) must flow in the direction of the arrow in the diode symbol when the diode is conducting. You'll need to work out whether the voltage applied to the diode in your circuit diagram causes it to conduct or not.